# Flask-Mail - Any way to request Read Receipt?

Tags: email, flask, flask-mail

I just spent a little time browsing similar questions on here, and it looks like some mail frameworks have a way of sending the proper signals to a mail client for the confirmation of read receipts.

The project on which I am working must have Read-Receipts requested as all the recipients have auto-sent read receipts enabled, and also have images blocked so I'm unable to use image-loading for tracking.

I'm most familiar with Python, Flask, and Flask-Mail, which is why I'm starting here to see if anyone knows a way to request this through these frameworks, or perhaps knows what to add to a to a mail header to request this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a little more research and testing, in the absence of a specific setting in Flask-Mail for read-receipts, it is possible to request them by defining the header `Disposition-Notification-To` using `extra_headers` in the Flask-Mail `Message()` definition in order to trigger a read-receipt request:

```
sender = 'sender@domain.com'
recipient = 'recipient@anotherdomain.com'

msg = Message(subject='Testing Read Receipt',
              recipients=[recipient],
              sender = ('Testy McTesterson', sender),
              extra_headers={'Disposition-Notification-To': sender})
```